# Как сгенерировать json php

Tags: php, json

На выходе пытаюсь получить:

```
{"labels":["S1","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8"],"values":[2.5,3.8,5,6.9,6.9,7.5,10,17]}
```

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result99993)) {
 $period = $row["period_id"];
 $type = $row["name_id"];
 $score = $row["score"];

$data2[] = [
    "labels" => ["$period"],
    "values" => [$score]
];
```

А выходит:

```
[{"labels":["Входное"],"values":["55"]},{"labels":["Ноябрь"],"values":["23.53"]},{"labels":["Январь"],"values":["92.86"]},{"labels":["Февраль"],"values":["31.58"]},{"labels":["Февраль"],"values":["80"]},{"labels":["Февраль"],"values":["45.45"]}]
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Если ты на выходе хочешь получить массив, то добавлять значения надо в массив

```
$labels = [];
$values = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result99993)) {
    $labels[] = $row["period_id"];
    $values[] = $row["score"];
}
```

Comment: `$labels = [];
$values = [];
$labels[] = $row["period_id"];
$values[] = $row["score"];

$data2 = [
    "labels" => ["$labels"],
    "values" => [$values]
];` А как дальше действовать?

Comment: @Евгений не `$data2 = [ "labels" => ["$labels"], "values" => [$values] ];`, а `$data2 = ["labels" => $labels, "values" => $values];`